# how to fetch all values in single variable using java script

Tags: javascript, ibm-bpm

i am retrieving the all values in a for loop but i want to insert those values in database using single variable.It possible to store all values to the single record.

```js
var emailId;

//log.info("testing 1234 = "+tw.local.EntityProMasterList.listAllSelected);

for (var i = 0; i < tw.local.EntityProMasterList.listAllSelected.listLength; i++){
    emailId = tw.local.EntityProMasterList.listAllSelected[i];
    log.info("testing 1 = "+emailId.value);
}

log.info("testing 1 = "+emailId.value);
```

Comment: Can we get the code for log.info()?

Comment: How do you want to store? You can store using concatenated string. You're already having them as an array

Comment: yes, i am getting the data like this 1164,1395,1396,1397,1398,1399,1744 but i need to store single record with multiple values. like record "A" stored single single data

Comment: i don't have to store concatenates string. each one i need to stored sigle record

Answer (score 1):

You can  user JSON.stringify() and save it as string:

```
var holder = {};
holder.var1 = "var1";
holder.var2 = "var2";
log.info("holder:"+JSON.stringify(holder));
```

The output will be:

holder:{"var1":"var1","var2":"var2"}

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is - given a list of values, how can I insert those values into the database as separate entries.  If this is correct there is a right way and a wrong way to do this.

The wrong way is to simply put all the SQL into a string and use one of the DB services in the system data toolkit to execute.  Something like -

```
insert into table blah values(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

This would be wrong because you are open to SQL injection attacks.  There is a different service for parameterized queries.  This takes 1 or more SQL statements and a list of parameters to use in them. The details are documented in the service so I won't repeat them here.  Basically you would modify your query to have the ? Character where you need the data from your array.  You then create arrays of parameters that fill out the values on execution.